# Como extrair um pedaço de um xml utilizando PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Como posso capturar/retornar tudo que esta entre as tags `<*:Body>` e `</*:Body>` utilizando PHP, de modo que não importe quantas linhas existam antes ou depois de ambas as tags?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ConsultarRequest>
   <Cliente>
    <sistema>XPTO</sistema>
   </Cliente>
   <numDDD>xx</numDDD>
   <numTerminal>xxxxxxxx</numTerminal>
  </ConsultarRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

O resultado final que espero é:

```
  <ConsultarRequest>
   <Cliente>
    <sistema>XPTO</sistema>
   </Cliente>
   <numDDD>xx</numDDD>
   <numTerminal>xxxxxxxx</numTerminal>
  </ConsultarRequest>
```

**Importante**: o XML possui estrutura variável. Em alguns casos dentro do body podem existir vários valores em um mesmo nível. Opcionalmente gostaria de fazer isso via regex, tags de intervalo `<soapenv:body>` e `</soapenv:body>`.

Comment: O código que postei usa DOMXPath e DOMXPath pode ser adaptado facilmente para pegar qualquer tag ou variação dela.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Não use RegEx para isso,** não é que não vai dar certo, mas se qualquer coisa mudar no xml SOAP vai ter que dar manutenção no teu regex com certeza, e até que a manutenção ocorra tudo vai estar quebrado.

O que você pode (e deve preferencialmente) usar é o `DOMDocument`+`DOMXapth` (ou outras APIs de DOM para PHP), exemplo que vai resolver o seu caso:

```
<?php

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ConsultarRequest>
   <Cliente>
    <sistema>XPTO</sistema>
   </Cliente>
   <numDDD>xx</numDDD>
   <numTerminal>xxxxxxxx</numTerminal>
  </ConsultarRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$encontrou = false;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadxml($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

//Registrado o namespace para que a query funcione com ele
$xpath->registerNamespace('soapenv', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');

//O `//` busca o elemento <soapenv:Body> em QUALQUER parte do documento
$elementos = $xpath->query("//soapenv:Body");

//Verifica se retornou pelo menos um elemento
if ($elementos) {
    //Dentro <soapenv:Body> pega o primeiro elemento, que no seu exemplo é o `<ConsultarRequest>`, mas pode variar dependendo da resposta
    $node = $elementos[0]->getElementsByTagName('*')->item(0);

    //Se encontrar um elemento então entra na IF
    if ($node) {
        $encontrou = true;

        //Pega o conteudo do primeiro elemento, incluindo ele, e transforma em uma string
        $html = $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $node );

        echo 'Resultado:<br>';
        echo htmlentities($html); //O htmlentities é somente para você visualizar no navegador, ele é dispensável
    }
}

if (!$encontrou) {
    echo 'não foram encontrados elementos';
}
```

Se vai manipular/ler os dados de `<ConsultarRequest>` talvez nem precise transformar em string, nem precisará da string para nada, o proprio `DOMNode` e `DOMXpath` vão resolver todos seus problemas, como por exemplo:

```
<?php

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ConsultarRequest>
   <Cliente>
    <sistema>XPTO</sistema>
   </Cliente>
   <numDDD>xx</numDDD>
   <numTerminal>xxxxxxxx</numTerminal>
  </ConsultarRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$encontrou = false;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadxml($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$sistema = $xpath->query("//ConsultarRequest/Cliente/sistema");
$ddd = $xpath->query("//ConsultarRequest/numDDD");
$terminal = $xpath->query("//ConsultarRequest/numTerminal");

echo 'Sistema: ', $sistema[0]->nodeValue, '<br>';
echo 'ddd: ', $ddd[0]->nodeValue, '<br>';
echo 'Terminal: ', $terminal[0]->nodeValue, '<hr>';
```

Comment: Este tópico foi aberto para solucionar um problema que estou tendo neste projeto: https://github.com/crphp/webservice, onde ao submeter para a classe Soap (src/Soap.php) um xml literal, é retornado erro, uma vez que __soapCall adicionar os mesmos cabeçalhos ao disparar a request...

Comment: @FábioJânio você pode adaptar o XPath como desejar, eu te dei o caminho basta você estudar e adaptar a todas suas necessidade, ainda mais se são variantes, entenda a resposta como o caminho e como um estudo para ti. Aliais, o primeiro código que postei pega qualquer coisa dentro do :Body, o segundo vc pode criar querys para todas situações e com IFs ir checando qual é qual.

Comment: Obrigado. Realizei os ajustes necessários. Veja em: https://github.com/crphp/webservice/blob/master/src/Soap.php linha 72 a 85