# Manipular XML vindo de resposta a Webservice em PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-service, soap

já vi algumas respostas dessas aqui em outras linguagens, mas não em PHP.
Alguém sabe como posso manipular esse xml que retorna de um Webservice?
Gostaria de pegar os dados específicos que estão em

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header></env:Header>
<env:Body>
    <ns1:consultarProcessoResposta xmlns="http://www.cnj.jus.br/tipos-servico-intercomunicacao-2.2.2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.cnj.jus.br/intercomunicacao-2.2.2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.cnj.jus.br/mni/cda" xmlns:ns1="http://www.cnj.jus.br/servico-intercomunicacao-2.2.2/">
        <sucesso>true</sucesso>
        <mensagem>Processo consultado com sucesso</mensagem>
        <processo>
            <ns2:dadosBasicos numero="30003994220198060010" competencia="2" classeProcessual="436" codigoLocalidade="95" nivelSigilo="0" intervencaoMP="false" tamanhoProcesso="5575922" dataAjuizamento="20190405152937">
                <ns2:polo polo="AT">
                    <ns2:parte assistenciaJudiciaria="false" intimacaoPendente="0">
                        <ns2:pessoa nome="CONDOMINIO VILLAGE DA PRAIA DO ICARAI" dataNascimento="19860213" numeroDocumentoPrincipal="10461812000198" tipoPessoa="juridica">
                            <ns2:documento codigoDocumento="10461812000198" emissorDocumento="Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil" tipoDocumento="CMF" nome="CONDOMÍNIO VILLAGE DA PRAIA DO ICARAÍ" />
                            <ns2:endereco cep="61620130">
                                <ns2:logradouro>Rua Manoel Moura</ns2:logradouro>
                                <ns2:numero>161</ns2:numero>
                                <ns2:complemento>atualmente rua raimundo mendes de carvalho</ns2:complemento>
                                <ns2:bairro>Icaraí</ns2:bairro>
                                <ns2:cidade>CAUCAIA</ns2:cidade>
                                <ns2:estado>CE</ns2:estado>
                            </ns2:endereco>
                        </ns2:pessoa>
                        <ns2:advogado nome="MARIA FREITAS GOMES ROLIM" inscricao="CE0010621A" numeroDocumentoPrincipal="31117406334" intimacao="false" tipoRepresentante="A" />
                    </ns2:parte>
                </ns2:polo>
                <ns2:polo polo="PA">
                    <ns2:parte assistenciaJudiciaria="false" intimacaoPendente="0">
                        <ns2:pessoa nome="JOAO SANTOS DA SILVA" sexo="M" nomeGenitora="MARIA DE LOURDES SANTOS DA SILVA" dataNascimento="19660603" numeroDocumentoPrincipal="30314828320" tipoPessoa="fisica" nacionalidade="BR">
                            <ns2:documento codigoDocumento="27088200701" emissorDocumento="Justiça Eleitoral" tipoDocumento="TE" nome="JOAO SANTOS DA SILVA" />
                            <ns2:documento codigoDocumento="30314828320" emissorDocumento="Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil" tipoDocumento="CMF" nome="JOAO SANTOS DA SILVA" />
                            <ns2:endereco cep="60510202">
                                <ns2:logradouro>Rua Doutor Júlio Maciel</ns2:logradouro>
                                <ns2:numero>1393</ns2:numero>
                                <ns2:complemento>CASA A</ns2:complemento>
                                <ns2:bairro>Henrique Jorge</ns2:bairro>
                                <ns2:cidade>FORTALEZA</ns2:cidade>
                                <ns2:estado>CE</ns2:estado>
                            </ns2:endereco>
                        </ns2:pessoa>
                    </ns2:parte>
                </ns2:polo>
                <ns2:assunto principal="true">
                    <ns2:codigoNacional>10468</ns2:codigoNacional>
                </ns2:assunto>
                <ns2:magistradoAtuante>13968157320</ns2:magistradoAtuante>
                <ns2:outroParametro nome="mni:pje:pedidoLiminarOuAntecipacaoTutela" valor="false" />
                <ns2:valorCausa>1331.31</ns2:valorCausa>
                <ns2:orgaoJulgador codigoOrgao="92" nomeOrgao="17ª Unidade do Juizado Especial Cível" instancia="ORI" codigoMunicipioIBGE="2304400" />
            </ns2:dadosBasicos>
        </processo>
    </ns1:consultarProcessoResposta>
</env:Body>
```

Comment: já tentou usar o `simplexml_load_string`?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como extrair um pedaço de um xml utilizando PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321952/como-extrair-um-peda%c3%a7o-de-um-xml-utilizando-php)

Comment: Recebo esse XML de uma requisição a um Webservice. Então quero extrais desse XML informações que contém nele como logradouro, número, complemento, etc... quero separar essas informações em PHP.

Comment: A resposta para sua pergunta está nesse link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/321974/137387 como informou @Vinicius.Silva